# Returning centroid coordinates from footprint coordinates using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, footprint

I have a set of footprint coordinates in KML. However I do not have the building coordinates.

How do I return building's centroid (single point) by using the footprint coordinates in KML using QGIS?

Comment: KML coordinates should already be latitude longitude, longitude

Comment: you can copy and paste from google earth to notepad directly to see the coordinates, in FME you can use the CoordinateExtractor and set specify coordinates in the settings (cog) https://www.safe.com/transformers/coordinate-extractor/

Comment: If you have the footprints - you have the building coordinates surely?  Can you define what the difference is between "building coordinates" and "building footprints" - do you want a centroid (single point)?

Comment: @MappaGnosisyes i want a centroid.

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS, you can get the coordinates of a *single feature* by clicking on it with the Identify tool. This opens the Identify Results window, which show's the feature's attributes. Click the small arrow next the the section called "Derived" to see additional information like the coordinates of the spot you clicked on, the coordinates of the nearest vertex of the feature, its area (if it's a polygon) and so on.

To get the coordinates of all the features added to the attribute table, use the Field Calculator with expressions like this:

- to get the X coordinate of the centroid of the building footprint (which will be longitude if the layer is in EPSG:4326), use this expression: `x(centroid($geometry)`
- to get the Y coordinate of the centroid, use `y(centroid($geometry)`
- to get the centroid coordinates together in [WKT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) (it will look like `POINT (X Y)`), use `geom_to_wkt(centroid($geometry))`
- to get the X and Y coordinates of a specific vertex, use `$x_at(n)` and `$y_at(n)`, where `n` is the vertex number
- to get the entire geometry of the polygon in WKT format (this will give you the coordinates of every vertex), use `geom_to_wkt($geometry)`

QGIS cannot edit the fields of a KMZ/KML file, so either save it as a different format or make the new field(s) virtual fields, which are stored in the project file instead of the source data file.